Allocating Kernel Space Memory for a PCI Device and Mapping to User Space Using UIO
I’m working on a project where I need to allocate memory from kernel space (DMA) for a specific PCI device. The goal is to allocate this memory in user space using ioctl calls(just like doing regular malloc, only added different pci device each time) to the kernel space. Additionally, I’m using the Userspace I/O (UIO) framework to access this memory from user space.
this is the ioctl header
#define DMA_ALLOC _IOR('A', 1, u64)

struct DMA_mesg
{
  u64 pci_dev;
  u64 size;
};

this is kernel space
struct uio_info kpart_info = {
    .name = "DMA_region",
    .version = "0.1",
    .irq = UIO_IRQ_NONE,
};
static long my_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, u64 arg) {
    dma_addr_t dma_handle;
    gfp_t gfp=GFP_KERNEL | GFP_DMA | __GFP_ZERO;
    struct pci_dev *pPci_dev;
    struct DMA_mesg *msg = kzalloc(sizeof(struct DMA_mesg), GFP_DMA);
    struct uio_info *info;
    if (copy_from_user(msg, (void *)arg, sizeof(struct DMA_mesg)))
        return -EFAULT;
    pPci_dev=(struct pci_dev *)(msg->pci_dev);

    switch (cmd) {
        case DMA_ALLOC:
            {
                info = kzalloc(sizeof(struct uio_info), GFP_KERNEL);
                if (IS_ERR(info)) {
                    ret = PTR_ERR(info);
                    pr_err("can't malloc info ");
                }
                /* Initialize the info structure. */
                *info = kpart_info;
                info->mem[0].size = msg->size;
                mem = dma_alloc_coherent(pPci_dev->dev, msg->size, &dma_handle, gfp);
                info->mem[0].addr = dma_handle;
                info->mem[0].memtype = UIO_MEM_PHYS;
                 
                //where does it registered? 
                if (uio_register_device(pPci_dev->dev, info))
                {
                    pr_err("canot register uio device ");
                }
                return 0;
            }
        default:
            return -ENOTTY; // Unsupported command
    }
}

How can I know what registered /dev/uioX, and pass it to the user space, or pass from the user space the name of the file from which I can do mmap later(it can be diffrent from the uio files)?
I don't want do save in the user space the current number of /dev/uioX and then to update it after DMA_ALLOC and "DMA_FREE", because different processes are using that framework of UIO on my system

This code is extremely dubious. How does user space even know what pci_dev pointer value to use?

This is on a different driver that I have written. To enhance modularity, I am requesting a PCI pointer from another driver using IOCTL.

UIO would use the wrong mechanism to mmap DMA coherent mappings. The DMA handle value is a "bus address" rather than a physical address.
